# TikZ curved callout

Tags: tikz-pgf, callout

What is the easiest way to get a curved callout? It seems the callout library does not support it so it seems a custom callout must be done.

Here's my MWE with a drawing of the desired result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

  \tikzset{
  bub/.style 2 args =   {
                         rectangle callout, rounded corners=2mm,
                         anchor=#2, draw, callout absolute pointer={#1},
                         inner sep=5mm, outer sep=0pt,
                         thick},
                        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{curved callout}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node at (0,0) [bub={(0,-4)}{north west}]
    {
      not curved callout
    };

\end{tikzpicture}\end{frame}\end{document}
```

[image]